# How to make filter transparent in dc.js charts

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to make a bar chart using dc.js. Users are able to select a portion of the data by clicking and dragging on a filter. However, the difficulty is that when this happens, on my website, the filter is completely black and the data selected is obscured:
[image: Black filter]

What should happen is, the filter should be partially transparent, as in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d50nB.png) from the [home page of dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/), so that the selected data can still be seen.

Here is the sample code which I am using to generate my page. I am using Crossfilter version 1.3.14, d3.js version 3.5.17 and dc.js 2.1.9.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/dc.css.min"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/dc.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = "data/page.csv";
    d3.csv(data, function(error, records) {
        var ndx = crossfilter(records);
        var keyDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.key;});
        var valueGroup = keyDimension.group().reduceCount();

        var graph = dc.barChart("#graph");
        graph.width(500)
             .height(300)
             .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,15]))
             .xUnits(function(){return 50;})
             .dimension(keyDimension)
             .group(valueGroup);
        graph.render();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the minified dc files (dc.min.css, dc.min.js, dc.min.js.map) with their full equivalents (dc.css, dc.js, dc.js.map) downloaded from Github, and now the filter displays as normal.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you got the wrong CSS, or no CSS at all. Thanks for following up!

Comment: Ah, now I see it - I had written dc.css.min instead of dc.min.css in my HTML.